# Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:pom:3.1.0 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven

I have create project using Maven. Below is my POM File Entry

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>student-services</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>student-services</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <docker.image.prefix>hello-howtodoinjava</docker.image.prefix>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <repository>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</repository>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>

                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I am getting below error in eclipse while building project

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:pom:3.1.0 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:pom:3.1.0 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out    pom.xml /student-services   line 1  Maven Configuration Problem

I tried below option but still error persist

1.Locate the {user}/.m2/repository
2. In the Search field in upper right of window, type ".lastupdated". Windows will look through all subfolders for these files in the directory.
3. Remove all the .lastupdated files.
4. Go back into Eclipse, Right-click on the project and select Maven > Update Project.
5. Select "Force Update of Snapshots/Releases".

I am using eclipse version -Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
Please let me know how to resolve this

Comment: The connection `timed out` looks like a network/firewall/proxy issue...

Comment: `mvn -U` disregards the update interval.